# Architectural tips on implementing GUI logic

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, architecture

So I'm implementing a svg-editor-like GUI on one application I'm working here. These are some examples of the logic that would be needed on it:

- If the user clicks with the right button on the canvas, a new node should be created, and subsequent nodes should be "linked" with a line, forming a polygon
- If the user clicks with the left button on a node, I should move the entire set of polygons accordingly to the mouse position
- The user is able to remove nodes
- Selected nodes should be colored differently
- The user is able to select multiple nodes by pressing SHIFT and clicking on nodes

And so on.

I've already implemented all of these items, but I didn't liked the end result, mainly because I had to use a lot of flags to manipulate states (mouse clicked && left button && not moving? do this), and surely this code could be more elegant. So I've researched a little and came to these options:

- Pipeline pattern: I would create classes that would handle *each* logical event separately, and use a priority order to provide what to do/what would be handed first, and how the event would propagate to the subsequent Pipeline items.
- MVC: this is the most common response but how I could use it to make the code more clean is very blurry to me at the moment.
- State Machine: That would be nice but managing the granularity of the state machine would be complicated

So I'm asking the S.O. gurus on tips on how to build a better and happier code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest separating the logic for the mapping of UI inputs to a specific operation into dedicated objects.  Lets's call them Sensor object.  Not knowing your implementation language, I'll be generic with this, but you should get the idea.

```
OperationSensor
+ OnKeyDown
+ OnKeyPress
+ OnKeyUp
+ OnLeftMouseDown
+ OnLeftMouseUp
+ OnNodeSelect
+ OnNodeDeselect
+ OnDragStart
+ OnDragStop
```

Let's say you have a central class that aggregates all the various UI inputs, `UiInputManager`.  It uses the language specific mechanisms to listen for keyboard and mouse input.  It also detects basic operations such as detecting that if the mouse is depressed, and then moved, that is a logic "drag".

```
UiInputManager
// event listeners
+ keyboard_keydownHandler
+ keyboard_keyupHandler
+ mouse_leftdownHandler
+ mouse_rightdownHandler
// active sensor list, can be added to or removed from
+ Sensors
```

The UiInputManager is NOT responsible for knowing what operations those inputs are causing.  It simply notifies its Sensors in a language specific way.

```
foreach sensor in Sensors
    sensor.OnDragStarted
```

or, if the sensors listen for logical events issued by the UiInputManager

```
RaiseEvent DragStarted
```

What you have now is the plumbing to route input to the OperationSensor subclasses.  Each OperationSensor has the logic just pertaining to a single operation.  If it detects the operation's criteria has been met then it creates the appropriate Command object and passes it back up.

```
// Ctrl + zooms in, Ctrl - zooms out
ZoomSensor : OperationSensor

   override OnKeyDown
   {
      if keyDown.Char = '+' && keyDown.IsCtrlDepressed
         base.IssueCommand(new ZoomCommand(changeZoomBy:=10)
      elseif keyDown.Char = '-' && keyDown.IsCtrlDepressed
         base.IssueCommand(new ZoomCommand(changeZoomBy:=-10)                                 
   }
```

I would recommend that the command objects pass from the Sensors to the UiInputManager.  The manager can then pass them into your command processing subsystem.  This gives the manager an opportunity to perhaps notify the Sensors that an operation completed, allowing them to reset their inner state if needed.

Multi-step operations can be handled in two different ways.  You can either implement inner state machines inside a SensorOperation, or you can have a "step 1" sensor create a "step 2" sensor and add it to the active sensor list, possibly even removing itself from the list.  When "step 2" completes, it can re-add the "step 1" sensor and remove itself.

Comment: So you're saying that he should use a pipeline as he stated in his question?

Comment: I was suggesting something new.  (I think) he stated he wished to use a pipeline for capturing and funneling the events, which would then chain into subsequent events handlers until the end hanlder deals with the event.  I focused on the operations being performed instead of the events triggering them.  Though if the OP clarified his pipleine idea I could compare/contrast a bit more.  I look forward to the OP replying to see his take on it.

Comment: In fact it was something on this fashion that I was thinking, very well explained! Glad to see that I was looking on the right direction :). One point from my idea that lead me to the pipeline pattern was about action priorities and the need to "break" the sensor notification when some command would explicitly not propagate the event down the chain. This can easily implemented using a set with a priority instead a list, and making the Sensor events to return some code flag, or even a boolean as return value to indicate the process to continue or break. Thanks!

Comment: Btw: great idea to break the Multi-step operations in smaller Sensors. This makes the state machine much more simple and clear to use.

Answer (score 3):

a *bit* late to the show, but I'd like to add that the common pattern for this is the mediator pattern where you move the complexity of the interactions between the various nodes to a separate class, the mediator (say a ConnectionCreator class). see designpatterns by Gamma and colleagues: http://ebookbrowse.com/addison-wesley-gamma-helm-johnson-vlissides-design-patterns-elements-of-reusable-object-oriented-pdf-d11349017

Answer (score 2):

Martin Fowler has [a good writeup](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) on MVC and related patterns. Also you may want to take a look at the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) for letting UI elements find out how they should behave (i.e. when a click on a node should move it or delete it etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using the command pattern to implement the action execution. I'm more focused on fixing the logic mess right now.

Answer (score 0):

For UIs MVC is pretty universal these days.  Very briefly, the M (model) contains state, V (view) shows visual elements, C (controller) dispatches inbound user actions such as mouse clicks.  The goal is for the model to not care directly about the view, except for perhaps firing events.

I would perhaps put the 'smarts' in the models.  The model would know when a node is selected, its adjacent nodes forming the polygon, state machines, etc.  This design gives you several benefits.  It's independent from the details of the UI rendering; so you can made major view changes without disrupting the core functionality.  It also makes it much easier to unit test.